# Is there an equivalent to a 'subroutine' in the Python language?

Tags: python

What is the syntax for creating, calling, and exiting subroutines in Python?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Python and has absolutely nothing to do with Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 3):

It's called a "function"; it begins with "def" and (usually) ends with "return".

Docs: http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/functions.html

> The keyword def introduces a function definition. It must be followed
>   by the function name and the parenthesized list of formal parameters.
>   The statements that form the body of the function start at the next
>   line, indented by a tab stop. The first statement of the function body
>   can optionally be a string literal; this string literal is the
>   function's documentation string, or docstring. There are tools which
>   use docstrings to automatically produce printed documentation, or to
>   let the user interactively browse through code; it's good practice to
>   include docstrings in code that you write, so try to make a habit of
>   it.